# Django Toggle Div on Search Query

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

**UPDATE**
The solution is in the comments.

**Original Post**
I have a basic search query to find customers on one of my forms in my Django project. It returns results from the database in an HTML table. The query is executed by clicking the search button. I want to hide the div encapsulating the table when the query has not been executed.

Because the JS function is executed when the search button is clicked, the table only shows momentarily until the page reloads.

What is the convention for displaying a div after a query is executed, without having a constant toggle button?

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CustomerResultsView(ListView):
    model = CustomerName
    template_name = 'parent/child.html'
    context_object_name = 'filtered_customers'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form1'] = FilterForm(initial={
            'name': self.request.GET.get('name', ''),
            'filter_field': self.request.GET.get('filter_field', '')
        })
        context['users'] = self.request.user
        context['form'] = Customer()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('name')
        filter_field = self.request.GET.get('filter_field')
        if query:
            return CustomerName.objects.filter(
                Q(('%s__icontains' % filter_field, query))
            )
        else:
            return {}
```

**child.html**

```
        <form method="GET">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Customer Lookup</legend>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                {{ form1|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info mt-4" value="Search" onclick="showDiv()">
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="custTabDiv" style="display:none">
            <table id="testTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="th-sm" scope="col">First</th>
                        <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Last</th>
                        <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Phone</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {% for name in filtered_customers %}
                            <tr>
                                <td id="test" onclick="customerNameValidation()">{{ name.first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ name.last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ name.phone }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

<script>
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("custTabDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried to only display the div if URL params are not equal to `null` or empty string using: `<script> var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var name = url.searchParams.get("name");
if(name !== null || name !== '') {
    document.getElementById("custTabDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>`
but the div is now always visible. I opened the console and checked the values of "name" and it was "foo" when the query had been executed, and `null` before.

Comment: The results are loaded via a regular form GET/HTTP request and not AJAX?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, not using AJAX

Comment: Wrapping the entire `div` in a `{% if request.GET %}` and not using JS at all would work? When the form is submitted the page is reloaded so JS is not required

Comment: @IainShelvington That worked perfectly! The first time the page is loaded is a GET request right? If so, why does this code execute only after the form submission GET?

Comment: `if request.GET` only returns `True` if there are GET/query params in the request, when there are no GET/query params `request.GET` is an empty dict which is "False"

Comment: @IainShelvington You have been incredibly insightful!

Comment: Glad I could help